# Does busybox have a tool for dumping 4 byte words as hex on a little endian machine?

Tags: text-processing, busybox, binary

I am trying to use busybox to dump files in /sys and /proc.

I happen to have an embedded device with busybox 1.31.

I noticed that xxd does not have the -e option for little endian.

I can't figure out how to do this in od or hexdump either, with busybox's limited set of options.

Any ideas?

Example of what does not work:

```
# hexdump fsl,mf-mix-wakeup-irq
0000000 c007 0000 0000 007d 0000 0000 4001 4006

# od -X fsl,mf-mix-wakeup-irq
0000000         0000c007        007d0000        00000000        40064001
0000020
```

This is the byte order that I want (from the source code):

```
0x7c00000 0x7d00 0x0 0x1400640
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show what sort of output you get (with e.g. `od -c`), and what you want to get instead? What are the files?

Comment: Is your data in machine endianness or not? What's wrong with `xxd -g4` or `od -tx4`?

Answer (score 1):

Gilles had the solution:

```
# xxd -g4 fsl,mf-mix-wakeup-irq
00000000: 07c00000 00007d00 00000000 01400640  ......}......@.@
```

Note that various od options are invalid in busybox:

```
# od -tx4 fsl,mf-mix-wakeup-irq
od: invalid option -- 't'
BusyBox v1.31.0 (2021-02-24 17:49:57 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: od [-aBbcDdeFfHhIiLlOovXx] [FILE]
```

Comment: ok, right, Busybox has two versions of `od`, the one in `od_bloaty.c` is enabled only if `ENABLE_DESKTOP` is set, so the one on my Debian is more featureful, it does have `od -t x4`.